# How to auto pick pictures from wikimedia representing an item from arbitrary words?

Tags: image, web, automation

I want my site to automatically load pictures from wikimedia (or any other no-license site) to represent food items (on my [nutrition site](https://v-nut.r-motiv.net)*) 
I haven't done anything like this before and was wondering if anyone has any experience with this.

For example, the string "lentils, pink, cooked, with salt" would generate a picture of cooked pink lentils. And if that not exist just some pink lentils. And if that not exist just any lentils.

Do I just try any combination for "pink" "lentils" and "cooked" or any synonyms from it? Then how?
Do I use an API?
Is there a better site than wikimedia? Is there already some sort algorithm for this? Or any tips at all?

Of course I am gonna let users know the picture is a guess and let them even approve if this is the right one. It doesn't have to be perfect and can grow.
I am doing this with js and store results with PHP/MySQL, but I think the question is not language dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the Wikimedia Commons API for searching and retrieving images based on input string. Follow these steps:

- Parse input string:
  Extract relevant keywords from the input string. In your example, keywords would be "lentils," "pink," "cooked," and "with salt."
- Construct API query:
  Use extracted keywords to construct a query for Wikimedia Commons API. Here's an example using Python:

```
import requests

def build_api_query(keywords):
    query = " ".join(keywords)
    return f'https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=json&srsearch={query}&srnamespace=6&srlimit=10&origin=*'
```

- Fetch and display image:
  Use the API query to fetch results and display image on your website. Example with Python's `requests`:

```
def fetch_image(keywords):
    api_url = build_api_query(keywords)
    response = requests.get(api_url)
    data = response.json()

    if len(data['query']['search']) > 0:
        first_result = data['query']['search'][0]
        image_url = f'https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:{first_result["title"]}'
        # Display image using image_url
    else:
        # Handle case when no image is found
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the WikiMedia API:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

You can use the API to search for images based on keywords like "lentils" or "cooked lentils" and retrieve the URLs of the images that match your search criteria. Once you have the URLs, you can display the images on your site.

If that is not "enough" I think you have to fall back to AIs and let you generate images of your desire (StableDiffusion / Midjourney ..)

Comment: I had to pick an answer, but know that I very much appreciate you added the possible AIs for it, which might actually be the ultimate solution although I started programming mediawiki API. The combined asnwer of you and @SolessChong above is actually the complete answer Iw as looking for. Thank you.